# "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view" other possible reason for this error

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WooCommerce REST API on our website for a long time, but today, suddenly i received error:

```
{
"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
"message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
}
```

My question is, what the possible reason for this, again, I'm using this API for a long time and I don't know why it suddenly receiving an error today. I updated my wordpress/woocommerce and all other plugins. I also tried to deactivate plugins to detect what cause this error but no luck I can't make it work again.

Comment: Please try changing your API key/secret with a read/write permission.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i tried your suggestion, but still the same :(

Comment: SSL Certificate expired and your verify_ssl true?

Comment: SSL is fine too.

Comment: What is the endpoint you are calling.?

Comment: This https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/?per_page=100&consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211921/discussion-between-mujuonly-and-ako-si).